# Excel, calculate +8 weeks to the nearest Wednesday (or Sunday)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date

We have a business process that requires us to calculate

```
(TODAY + 8 weeks) to the nearest Sunday or Wednesday.
```

For example
 - Today is 07/12.
 - 8 weeks is 01/02/18
 - This is a Thursday. Count to the nearest Wednesday or Sunday in the past [1]. Count to the nearest Wednesday or Sunday in the future [3]
 - Select day with the lowest number of hops between the calculated date. Therefore we select Wednesday 31/01/18
 - If it is a Friday and there is a tie (-2 to Wednesday, +2 to Sunday) select the Sunday.

I'm happy with Excel to the point of `=TODAY()+(8*7)` but the next step to '`is this a Wednesday or Sunday, if not count forward and back until it is both then compare the two values and select the closest` is well beyond me. I assume it needs some VB but this isn't something I am familiar with (although I would be able to do this in powershell however, I'm not incapable just unfamiliar).

Is anyone able to get me started?

Ultimately I'd like to embed the results into a Word Document but that can come later.

Answer (score 4):

As you never want to go back more than one day (from the 56 initially added) <sup>[1]</sup>, it would be sufficient to add 56, subtract 2 and then find the next occurrence of a Wednesday or a Sunday.

You can do that using [`WORKDAY.INTL` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D) (Excel 2010 or later) like this:

`=WORKDAY.INTL(TODAY()+8*7-2,1,"1101110")`

`WORKDAY.INTL` can be customised to define the "working days" with a string like `"1101110"` - the string is of 7 `1/0` values starting with Monday and ending with Sunday where 0 represents a working day and 1 a non-working day, so `"1101110"` defines Wednesday and Sunday as the only working days

In older versions of Excel you can get the same result with this formula

`=MIN(TODAY()+8*7+6-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+8*7-{2,5}))`

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Explanation: the nearest Sunday or Wednesday can never be more than 2 days away in either direction and when date+56 = Friday Patrick says he wants to pick the Sunday.....so if date+56 is a Thursday or Monday then you need to go back 1, any other situation you either keep date+56 or go forwards.*

Comment: I'm missing where you get the initial assumption of not wanting to go back more than one day.

Comment: @fixer1234, just deduced from the description - the nearest Sunday or Wednesday can never be more than 2 days away in either direction and when date+56 = Friday Patrick says he wants to pick the Sunday.....so if date+56 is a Thursday or Monday then you need to go back 1, any other situation you either keep date+56 or go forwards......

Comment: OK, very clever.  +1

Comment: Very shrewd, Barry.

Answer (score 2):

How does this work for you?  It should calculate the closest Sunday or Wednesday 8 weeks in the future.

To verify it works, Place a date in A2.  You can change your reference from A2 to `Today()` after you are satisfied it works.


Place this formula in B2:

```
=(A2+(8*7)) - CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2+(8*7)),0,1,-1,0,1,-2,-1)
```

Place this formula in C2 to check the results:

```
=TEXT(B2,"DDD")
```

To test it, place your dates in A2 and check your calendar. 

If your weekday does not start on Sunday, then you can adjust 4 in the condition test of the `IF()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use just the FALSE part of the IF function, i.e. just `=A2+(8*7) - CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2+(8*7)),0,1,-1,0,1,-2,-1)`?

Comment: @barry houdini, Yup.  It appears so.